# Rails: unexpected behaviour in Chrome and Firefox when refreshing invalid form page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, turbolinks

When a user refreshes the page after submitting an invalid form, the browser should attempt to resubmit the form. In Chrome and Firefox (but not Safari) the browser performs a `GET` request on the create/update url instead.

#### EDIT

Removing Turbolinks fixes the problem - all browsers correctly call `POST` on refreshing a submitted form page. It's not the [first time](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/issues/187) that a Chrome update breaks Turbolinks, does anyone have a workaround?

#### Instructions to replicate the problem

1. Set up a new rails app and scaffold a test model called `Thing`

   ```
   # using Ruby 2.3.1 and Rails 5.0.0
   rails new testapp & cd testapp
   rails generate scaffold Thing name:string
   rails db:create db:migrate db:test:prepare
   ```
2. Make `Thing.name` a required attribute

   ```
   # app/models/thing.rb
   class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :name, presence: true
   end
   ```
3. Start a server and - in a browser - navigate to `/things`
4. Attempt to create a new thing without providing a `name`, Rails will render the form again with the error `Name can't be blank`.
5. Use the browser to refresh the page.

#### Expected behaviour

The browser should resubmit the form (usually asking "are you sure?" or similar), and render the same form-with-errors page.

Looking at the server output, we should see:

```
# Navigate to /things 
Started GET "/things"
# Click on "New Thing"
Started GET "/things/new"
# Click on "Create Thing" without filling in "name"
Started POST "/things" # <= attempts to create, fails, renders the form with errors
# Refresh the page
Started POST "/things" # <= POST called, the form is resubmitted
```

#### Actual behavior

In Chrome and Firefox (but not Safari), on page refresh the browser sends a `GET` request to the `POST` url, effectively calling `index`.

Looking at the server output, I get:

```
# Navigate to /things 
Started GET "/things"
# Click on "New Thing"
Started GET "/things/new"
# Click on "Create Thing" without filling in "name"
Started POST "/things" # <= attempts to create, fails, renders the form with errors
# Refresh the page
Started GET "/things" # <= expected POST
```

#### It gets worse

The issue is the same for `edit` and `update`. Assuming we have a valid `Thing` with `id: 1` saved in the database, this happens in Chrome and Safari:

```
# Click on "Edit Thing"
Started GET "/things/1/edit"
# Delete the existing "name" and click on "Update Thing"
Started PUT "/things/1" # <= attempts to update, fails, renders the form with errors
# Refresh the page
Started GET "/things/1" # <= expected POST
```

If the url is not RESTful, or if you just happen to have no `index` or `show` views, reloading causes the app to throw a `"No route"` error.

#### Help

Has anyone experienced this before? I can't find any traces of this in the Rails repo issues, but maybe I'm looking at it the wrong way.

I also tried with Ruby `2.1.2` and Rails `4.0.4`, and got the same results.

Comment: This isn't a rails issue, it's because your browser is doing a get request.

Comment: @j-dexx the bit I can't understand is why would Chrome and Firefox perform a get request, while Safari performs a post?

Comment: Not that I can think of

Comment: @j-dexx to be clear, my problem is not with `GET` triggering `index`, it's with `GET` happening at all.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  But Rails isn't the one triggering a get request, your browser is.  Rails is responding with the index because it's a get request

Comment: Removing Turbolinks fixes the issue. Now Chrome, Safari, and Firefox all call `POST` on page refresh. I'll edit my question to reflect this, as "removing Turbolinks" hardly feels like a solution.

Comment: I currently have the same issue.

Comment: Is there any progress?

Comment: This issue is reported at https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/229

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm having the same problem! at last someone with the same problem.

I think it's because you might using turbolinks ver 5. or above. 
Downgrade your turbolinks to version before 5 (eg:ver 2.5.3) you should have the expected behaviour (browser resubmit the form and asking "are you sure?" or similar).

Using your 'how to replicate problem', i tried switching turbolink version couple times to make sure and confirm this result.

For now, if you do not want to remove turbolinks entirely, you can use earlier version.

Comment: Thanks so much! (It's not the best solution) But its the only (reasonable) one I found.